# Validate if path is for a hidden file or folder in unix, using python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to check whether a given file/folder path is hidden using python regex and filter hidden .sync/.archive data:

```
`filepath1 = "/home/ubuntu/.file"`
`filepath2 = "/home/ubuntu/.archiveddata"`
`filepath3 = "/home/ubuntu/.folder"`

if filepath1 matches with pattern:
     it is hidden file/folder
else:
     it is archived data
```

Comment: what pattern? ...

Comment: regex pattern to match with filepath.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
filepath = "/home/ubuntu/.myfile.txt"
is_hidden = bool(re.search(r'/\.[^/]+$', filepath))
print(is_hidden)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for a regular file inside a hidden directory, unless you remove the `$` and allow a match anywhere in the path. Example: `/home/ubuntu/.hidden/something.txt`.